# JSP syntax to switch between HTML and XML

Tags: html, xml, jsp, postback

I would like to have a single JSP page that will do the following:

- If the method is GET and the querystring is NULL, draw a HTML form with a TEXTAREA and SUBMIT button
- If the method is GET and the querystring is not NULL or the method is POST, genete an XML document using GET/POST variables

My first approach draft (test POST or GET) fails syntactically:

query.jsp

```
<%@ page import="..." %>
<%!
  private void to_xml() {
  ...                
  }
%>
<% if (request.getMethod()="POST") { %>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<%
  //generate XML 
  to_xml();
} 

else { 

  //draw HTML form
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>XML Query</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="query.jsp" method="post">
            <table cellpadding="2">
                <tr><td>Query:</td></tr>
                <tr><td><textarea name="query" cols="60" rows="10" ></textarea>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Go"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<% } %>
```

I'm sure that there is a better way to do this, but my experience w/ JSP is limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your concrete problem: in Java, strings are objects, not primitives. You need to compare objects by the [`Object#equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method, not by equality operator `==` (or even more incorrectly, the assignment operator `=`). This is not different when writing raw Java code straight in a JSP file instead of a Java class.

```xml
<% if (request.getMethod().equals("POST")) { %>
```

---

As to the better way, just use a servlet.

Put JSP in `/WEB-INF/query.jsp` to prevent direct access and remove all old fashioned *scriptlets* so that it becomes a fullworthy view.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>XML Query</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="query" method="post">
            <table cellpadding="2">
                <tr><td>Query:</td></tr>
                <tr><td><textarea name="query" cols="60" rows="10" ></textarea>
                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Go"></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Create a servlet which does the controlling job:

```java
@WebServlet(urlPatterns={"/query"})
public class QueryServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
            showJsp(request, response);
        } else {
            showXml(request, response);
        }
    }

    private void showJsp(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/query.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }

    private void showXml(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Open the page by http://localhost:8080/contextname/query.

I however wonder how it's useful to mix POST/GET here since you want to intercept on the query string as well. Just remove `method="post"` from the `<form>` and replace `service()` method name in above example by `doGet()`. This way the form submit URL becomes bookmarkable as well (which is what among others Google also does).

Comment: After reading your response, some contemplation, and some research, it appears what I really want is RESTful interface to Java.  While I could use Jersey or RESTEasy, perhaps implemented selected bits of JAX-RS will meet my needs.

Comment: That was also what I initially thought :) It's only another learning curve. Note that Jersey and RESTEasy are both concrete JAX-RS API implementations. Like as that Tomcat is a concrete JSP/Servlet API implementation.

Comment: I really only have two classes: Session and InfoObjects (BusinessObjects).  I need GET/POST/DELETE for Session (auth form/authenticate/logout) and GET for InfoObjects (get one object or multiple).  While I'm sure these frameworks would make this easy, I'm leary of adding additional complexity.  Is there a less-complex way?

Comment: Well, using a plain servlet is less complex. Basically, what I've put in my answer is everything you need. But using JAX-RS will give you way much more flexibility with regard to future changes and expansions. Note that JAX-RS is designed on top of the basic Servlet API. So, it is under the covers using a plain servlet, but just with all potential boilerplate/repetitions abstracted away so that you don't need to Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V the entire JSP/Servlet code, but, say, just add one more method.

Comment: Is there a way to pass a variable defined int the Servlet to the view?  Most of the examples that I've seen dynamically create the view.  I would like to be able to use something the <%= XXX %> syntax.

Comment: *Scriptlets* are discouraged since a decade: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files. Just set an attribute in request scope like `request.setAttribute("foo", foo)` and access it in the forwarded JSP by EL like `${foo}`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info and http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info.